# How to get the last value of __COUNTER__

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a macro that does something similar to the following:

```
#define MAKE_VALS(...) \
    int val1 = 0; \
    int val2 = 0; \
    :
    if(val1 == val2) \
    { \
        ... 
    }
```

and I need to use it multiple times within a single function. The trouble is, using it multiple times causes multiple definition errors due to multiple definitions of val1 and val2.

Using `__COUNTER__` with `##` would solve the problem, but I can't see how to get the correct variable names for the if statement? I can't use `__COUNTER__` again because I'd get the next value. I need a way to get the last value of `__COUNTER__`. Can it be done?

PS. I don't want to surround it with `{}`s to fix the problem. I've simplified the real problem here and using `{}`s causes other problems (that aren't important to what I'm asking).

Comment: Can't you define `val1` and `val2` **once** before running `MAKE_VALS`?

Comment: I won't answer unless you say what problems `{}` cause. Because that's the straight forward solution (w/ `do`).

Comment: @Jacob: no, because for the second use it would be val3 and val4, then on the next use val5 and val6 - ie. it would defeat the object of using the macro in the first place.

Comment: @Jan: No, I meant define `val1` and `val2` somewhere and then don't define them in `MAKE_VALS`, just set them to 0.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: and the un-straightforward solution is? (I would have to post a lot of code to explain the problems caused by using `{}`s - it would be pointless.)

Comment: If you need a lot of code to explain it you obviously doing something the wrong way.

Comment: @Jan: @litb's question is valid, why is creating a local scope such a problem for you? If you're using MAKE_VALS() several times within a large scope, maybe one of the inputs to the macro should be a number, then you can use token pasting to generate the two integers, for instance `val ## number` and `val ## number ## _`

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do (not what your solution is trying to do, but the actual use case)?

Comment: Why do you even need this to be a macro in the first place ? I'd be very surprised if this can't just be implemented with a (possibly inline) function.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever the purpose of this is, you can achieve that using several levels of macros:

```
#define MAKE_VALS(...) MAKE_VALS1(..., __COUNTER__)
#define MAKE_VALS1(..., counter) MAKE_VALS2(..., counter)
#define MAKE_VALS2(..., counter) \
   int val1##counter = 1; int val2##counter = 2; \
   val1##counter = whatever; val2##counter = hunoz;
```

This way, you can use `MAKE_VALS` more than once in the same scope, and every call will create a new set of variables. Note that without `MAKE_VALS1`, your variables would be named `val1__COUNTER__` and so on, and the extra level makes it the actual number.

It's a nice exercise in macro writing, but I agree with the guys before me who questioned if this is the right way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve. But enough has been said about that, so I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I was having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MAKE_VALS(m, n, ...) \
    int val ## m = 0; \
    int val ## n = 0; \
    :
    if(val ## m == val ## n) \
    { \
        ... 
    }
```

Use:

```
 MAKE_VALS(__LINE__,
           __LINE__, ... ); //second __LINE__ on next line
```

Put second `__LINE__` on next line to avoid having same value for both `m` and `n`.